# Why am I getting permission denied when running a Liquibase update?

Tags: liquibase, permission-denied, aws-codebuild

G'day, I'm running a CodeBuild job where I install the latest version of Liquibase and then run the update command. Liquibase appears to be installed however I get a permission denied when running update even though I have the appropriate IAM role and have execute permissions for all users. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There might be a possibility that the `update` command needs to be run with elevated privileges. Are you the root user? If not try running the update command using `sudo` and check